# High-Res or Vector 10m Topographic Line Map for Europe?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe

The USA puts out great free topographic line maps, but I can't find any free (topo line map) resources for the EU with enough detail to model the terrain. While I'd prefer 10m elevation between lines, I'd be happy with up to 100m. Do any such resources exist?

Comment: I googled your question title and came up with this - http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/ If that's not what you are looking for, please edit your question to it's clearer (also with links to US contour maps, as examples)

Comment: @philshem I don't know what to call them other than contour...the maps that have a physical line every so many feet. If I was doing one of a perfect cone, it would look like a darts target.

Comment: topographic maps? can you add a link in the question to the US maps you mean?

Comment: That's absolutely what I'm looking for. I've changed my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for a European wide contour dataset crossing all international borders at a resolution similar to the USA data produced by their mapping agencies? You are not asking for much then...

Do you think the European countries would organise themselves to collaborate on such mapping task? I am happy to be proven wrong!

Your only choices are to acquire each in country contour dataset and splice it into a single seamless data (no easy task but most likely to give you the resolution you are requiring), or use contours created from global datasets (so lower resolution) such as SRTM, a simple search on Google using the search term "contour data europe" threw up [Contour lines vector tiles Europe](https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/dataset/contours/europe/#9/66.4981/6.1303).